# Facebook Mobile App

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, mobile, web

I have a little question about Facebook Mobile Apps I have to make an Facebook App for web and mobile but I also want that the user like the page before entering the app on the mobile.
Now is my question: is it possible for mobile too? If yes, how?

Comment: Yes, if your Mobile app has is oauth enabled and the user has provided access to your App, once it is done you can check whether he has liked your page or not